# Rails3 seed data nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What am I doing wrong here?  The forms work but keep getting "undefined method `to_i' for :street1:Symbol" when trying to seed data.

**EDIT = If I do everything as a singular address (has_one instead of has_many) seed works.**

**EDIT 2 = See answer below for others...**

```
address.rb
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :street1, :street2, :city, :state, :zipcode, :deleted_at, :addressable_type, :addressable_id, :current, :full_address, :address_type
    belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
    scope :vendor, where("address_type='Vendor'")

    before_save :update_full_address

    def update_full_address
      unless self.street2.blank?
        street = self.street1 + "<br />" + self.street2 + "<br />" 
      else 
        street = self.street1 + "<br />"
      end
      citystatezip = self.city + ", " + self.state + " " + self.zipcode
      self.full_address = street + citystatezip
    end
end
```

vendor.rb

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :contact, :phone, :addresses_attributes
  has_many :addresses, :as => :addressable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |obj| obj.blank? }
end
```

seed data

```
require 'faker'

Vendor.delete_all
["Company A", "Company B", "Company C", "Company D"].each do |c|
  params = {:vendor => 
      {
        :name => c,
        :contact => Faker::Name.name,
        :phone => Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number,
        :addresses_attributes => {
          :street1 => Faker::Address.street_address,
          :city => Faker::Address.city,
          :state => Faker::Address.us_state_abbr,
          :zipcode => Faker::Address.zip_code,
          :address_type => "Vendor"
          }
      }
    } 
  Vendor.create!(params[:vendor]) 
end
```

---

Note the [] for an array when dealing with has_many.

```
require 'faker'

Vendor.delete_all
["Company A", "Company B", "Company C", "Company D"].each do |c|
  params = {:vendor => 
      {
        :name => c,
        :contact => Faker::Name.name,
        :phone => Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number,
        :addresses_attributes => [{
          :street1 => Faker::Address.street_address,
          :city => Faker::Address.city,
          :state => Faker::Address.us_state_abbr,
          :zipcode => Faker::Address.zip_code,
          :address_type => "Vendor"
          }]
      }
    } 
  Vendor.create!(params[:vendor]) 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :foo` is so that you can create forms which create associated records. When you're building things in code, there's no need to use this. You can create the associated records using the association names instead of "address_attributes". Here's one way of doing it, but Rails does expose a bunch of ways of doing this same thing...

```
["Company A", "Company B", "Company C", "Company D"].each do |c|
  vendor_address = Address.new :street1 => Faker::Address.street_address,
                               :city => Faker::Address.city,
                               :state => Faker::Address.us_state_abbr,
                               :zipcode => Faker::Address.zip_code,
                               :address_type => "Vendor"

  Vendor.create! :name => c,
                 :contact => Faker::Name.name,
                 :phone => Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number,
                 :addresses => [vendor_address]
end
```

If you are wanting to try and use the nested attributes way, then you don't need the `:vendor => {}` part of the hash, you can go straight into the params, and you need `addresses_attributes` to be an array, not a hash.

Comment: OK, found my problem with your response.  Did not turn address into an array for the has_many.  Instead of :addresses_attributes => {..} it should be :addresses_attributes => [{...}].  THANK YOU!